# Introducing a hyperbolic speed limit to a parameterized system

Tags: special-relativity, vectors, models

I have function $S$ representing a trend-fitted vector for five variables parameterized by time, $S(x(t),y(t),z(t),f(t),g(t))$ where $x,y,z,f,g \in C^2(\mathbb{R})$ (making $S \in C^2(\mathbb{R}^5)$) which represents a physical model of quantities changing.

Now, suppose to make the model more accurate, we wanted to introduce a maximum speed limit that the overall velocity could only asymptotically approach, like say, 500 units of length per unit of time, analogous to the hyperbolic geometry around the speed of light.

How do we implement and model a "speed limit" on the magnitude of the velocity of along each dimension?

Comment: is any of those variables related to the speed you want to limit?

Comment: @CarlosGauss Yes I'd like to limit the overall magnitude of all of them. Here's the kicker which may make this more difficult for you: I'd like different maximum speed limits for the different dimensions, so 5 different speed limits but with continuous variations between the functions.

Comment: so, for instance, you do not want to limit the values of x(t) but you want to limit the value of $\Delta x/\Delta t$?

Comment: The condition
$$
\frac{\dot x^2}{c_x^2}+...+\frac{\dot g^2}{c_g^2}\le 1
$$
limits the speed in $x$-direction to $c_x$ and so on and also limits the overall speed to a limit whose calculation I leave as an exercise.

Comment: @KurtG. Hi Kurt, a condition is necesserily not a "model," I'm asking how we change and modify the vector function to incorporate a special-relativity-like speed limit along each dimension. To do this, we might need some notion of the "energy" the system and reformulate the vector equations in terms of how much pseudo-kinetic energy they have in this abstract case.

Comment: @CarlosGauss Yep! At some point in the future I will also like to limit the overall values, but one step at a time you know? For now, I'm just looking to understand the mathematical nature of how we model an intrinsic speed limits.

Comment: @askquestions4 . How does SR lead to speed limits ? It allows for space like world lines that exceed the speed limit. Afaik the fact that physical objects cannot is a postulate of SR.

Comment: @KurtG. Okay, what would you claim is the appropriate framework for the "why" and "how" no physical object goes faster than light?

Comment: It is SR and GR as we know them. I did not claim in any way that they are inappropriate.

Comment: Okay, then for practical purposes, according to you, there is a speed limit, barring negative energy.